# highchart position label on xAxis value

Tags: highcharts

Using highchart, is there a way to add labels according to particular x / y Axis values ?

Using the [highchart's labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels), I'm able to write text at a given position in pixels, but I need to give a value from an axis as position.

For example, in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DdkDW/4/) I would like to set the label position on 'june', like the plot line.

how can I do this?

```
    labels: { 
           items : [{ 
               html : 'Summer starts here !' ,
               style : { 
                   left: '10px', 
                   //I need to set the left position as an xValue : the timestamp for the summer start.
                   top: '100px'
               }
           }] 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plotLine can have a label, take a look: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.label

Comment: Exactly what I needed,  thanks ! see the updated fiddle with this solution :  http://jsfiddle.net/DdkDW/5/

Answer (score 0):

You should set "on" value for tickmarkPlacement parameter

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Comment: thx for your help, adding tickmarkPlacement: 'on', avoid to need the weird '4.5', instead 5 is june.  its better.  but it doesn't help in the label placement. I'd like the "summer start" label to be written on the june month.